# Is it possible to virtualize a LAN?

Tags: networking, router, virtual-machine, vmware

I've got the following physical layout:

`VM -> Workstation -> Router -> Internet`

I'd like to end up with the following network layout:

```
Workstation -> Router1 -> Internet
VM          -> Router2 -> Internet
```

Where `Router1` and `Router2` are  the same physical router and the VM is running on the Workstation. Packets traveling from Workstation to VM need to follow this path:

```
Workstation -> Router1 -> Internet -> Router2 -> VM
```

such that VM sees Workstation's public IP instead of its private IP. **Can this be done?**

---

## Background

I am testing a [STUN server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) running in a virtual machine. The test requires the VM to locate Workstation's public IP (without the help of an external server).

Comment: You are going to need two routers, or a router with specialized firnware.  VMware can support multiple networks just fine.  You could setup two routers in VMs.

Comment: @Zoredache, please post a formal answer so I can comment on it. Comments are reserved for questions about the question.

Comment: I might do that at a later time when I am at a real computer.  I am on a phone at the moment.  If you have additional questions that you think would be raised, then you might want to edit them into your question.  If you have additional requirements that would preclude my answer hinted at by my comment those should added to your question also.

Comment: @Zoredache, I have questions that are specific to your answer. I cannot add them to the above question as they are not relevant to other answers that users may post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where **Router1 and Router2 are the same physical router** and the VM is running on the Workstation. Packets traveling from Workstation to VM need to follow this path **Workstation -> Router1 -> Internet -> Router2 -> VM**

This simply will not be possible, using any standard router.  A router will not direct packets out to the Internet if the packet is destined for a network it is directly connected to.  So about the only think you can do is something like this.  **Workstation -> Router1 -> VM**.

You probably can setup a network you can test things on, but will require a more complex setup then you probably wanted/expected.

Since you are running Vmware you can setup multiple virtual networks, and at least for VMs for testing.  You will need to create a bunch.  I think I would create networks like this.

VMs

- router 1 (connects workstation 1 to local network)

  - two interfaces one on VMnet0, and one on VMnet3
- router 2 (connects workstation 2 to local network)

  - two interfaces one on VMnet0, and one on VMnet4
- workstation 1 (client or server for testing)

  - one interface on VMnet3
- workstation 2 (client or server for testing)

  - one interface on VMnet4

Networks:

- VMnet0 - this your pre-existing bridged network for testing treat it as the external network
- VMnet3 - Host-only - DHCP disabled - This connects router 1 to workstation 1
- VMnet4 - Host-only - DHCP disabled - This connects router 2 to workstation 2

As for routers you could use something simple like the x86 version of DD-WRT or pfsense to get a pretty easy to use router.  For your testing you might actually might want to try a few different routers.

With a network setup like above packets between your two testing workstations would flow like this:

```
workstation 2 -> vmnet4 -> router 2 -> vmnet0 -> router 1 -> vmnet3 -> workstation 3
```

Comment: So I need at two physical routers and two public IPs? Remember, I want VM to see Workstation's public IP so I'm not sure a virtual network would help here.

Comment: The method I suggested doesn't required any physical hardware.  Just 4 virtual machines.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that `router 1` and `router 2` referred to  virtual machine names and not a physical routers. Thanks!